# A multiple choice question related to singularities , poles.

Tags: complex-analysis

1)Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ for all z$\in C$ such that $e^z\ne1$ then

> a) f is meromorphic
>
> b) the only singularities of f are poles
>
> c) f has infinitely many poles on the imaginary axis
>
> d) each pole of f is simple.

2)For z $\in C$, define $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{e^z-1}$ then

> a) f is entire
>
> b) the only singularities of f are poles
>
> c) f has infinitely many poles on the imaginary axis
>
> d) each pole of f is simple.

For 1st example I guess $e^z$  is entire function so option a) is correct. Also option b) is correct.
For 2nd example, also I guess options a) & b) are correct.
Please help me to get correct options.

Comment: multiple choice doesn't have to have only 1 correct answer

Comment: Why you have chosen the tag ''linear-algebra''?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using L'Hospital Calulate lim$_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac{z-2n\pi i}{e^z-1}$,hence deduce that the given function has simple poles at $z= 2n \pi i$, $\forall n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: So for 1st example last option is correct as well? What about 2nd example? Am I right there?

Comment: For problem $1$ all the options are correct and can you see that poles of function in problem $2$ is same as of function in $1$?